# how to access IIS server variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis, environment-variables

How do you access IIS "server variables" in Rails?  Are they passed in the ENV object?

We are using IIS to reverse proxy some Tomcat instances running a Rails app using JRuby. It looked like IIS can send server variables per request.  I would like to dynamically change view content based on the values of some of these server variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve server variables set by IIS by inspecting request object:

`request.env['some-variable']`